# NullpointerException when turning back to application

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragment, android-tablayout

I am using a TabLayout Activity with Fragments. Everything works correct, till another activity comes in front and when it returns to the TabLayout activity it !sometimes throws a nullpointexception.

This function is in my MainActivity. The code after super.onPause seems to be called when the user returns to the activity. This code informs a fragment that onpause is called.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    myPreferences.setBoolPreferences(MyPreferences.MY_PREFS_START, false);
    ((FragmentInterface) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition())).onRunPermissionChanged();

    flashLight.off();
}
```

Here is the code in the fragment.

```
@Override
public void onRunPermissionChanged() {
    if(myPreferences.getBoolPreferences(MyPreferences.MY_PREFS_START, MyPreferences.MY_PREFS_START_DEFAULT)){
        disco.start(viewBackground, imageViewDiscoBall);
    } else {
        stopDisco();
    }
}
```

However, I get a nullpointer exception on the preferences object, while this is initialised in the OnCreateView.

```
07-19 21:32:52.984 7829-7829/com.tomhogenkamp.NeonDiscoLight E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.tomhogenkamp.NeonDiscoLight, PID: 7829
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.tomhogenkamp.NeonDiscoLight/com.tomhogenkamp.NeonDiscoLight.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.tomhogenkamp.NeonDiscoLight.MyPreferences.getBoolPreferences(java.lang.String, boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3660)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3604)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3572)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:150)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1410)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.tomhogenkamp.NeonDiscoLight.MyPreferences.getBoolPreferences(java.lang.String, boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.tomhogenkamp.NeonDiscoLight.FragmentDisco.onRunPermissionChanged(FragmentDisco.java:104)
                                                                                   at com.tomhogenkamp.NeonDiscoLight.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:247)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:6374)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1412)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3639)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3604) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3572) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1410) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Sometimes it works, but sometimes throws a nullpointer exception. How can I solve this?

Comment: when you initialize the myPreferences?

Comment: In the OnCreateView method.

Comment: I dont know if helps but in onPause() you set the boolean preference but dont commit the changes try use an Saredpreferences.Editor and commit the changes

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your code could be executing before the view is created.

Notice how you said you initialize this value in `OnCreateView`. Depending on how fast the device is currently executing code, the code to call the fragment method is likely executing before `OnCreateView` in the fragment has been called which is where your nullpointer is coming from.

I see that you need to call methods in your main activity depending on the settings. Move this code to your fragment `OnCreateView` and make the methods you need to call in your MainActivity public.

then, access them in the fragment like so
`((MainActivity)getActivity()).stopDisco()`

Comment: But when the application is started all the fragments are created. So the preference object should exist right?

Comment: Please paste how you are initializing the variable, I didnt realize the nullpointer was in the mainactivity and not the fragment. I will edit my answer to better help you after you show me how it's initialized

Comment: The variable is global in the fragment and when the OnCreateView is called I initialise it (myPreferences = new My Preferences(getContext());). The nullpointer is in the fragment, I am calling the function from main activity. But for some reason the preference object is null sometimes. Like the object is destroyed?